# Reversible Ito Diffusions

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

I have given a diffusion equation
$$ dX_t = -\nabla V(X_t) \, dt + \sigma dB_t.$$

I found [here(1)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversible_diffusion) a characterization when $X_t$ is reversible, aslong as $\sigma=1$. Is this also true for $\sigma \neq 1$?

It is said [here(2)](https://hal.inria.fr/file/index/docid/120426/filename/dn06.pdf) that the general result for arbitrary $\sigma$ can be found [here(3)](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01571664). Unfortunately I do not have access to this document, and I also assume that the notation will probably be unreadable for me and not as plain and clean as [here(1)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversible_diffusion).

Therefore, I would like to know if it is easy to get from [here(1)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversible_diffusion) to the general case where $\sigma \neq 1$.

Also I would like to know if the stationary measure $\mu$ is unique if $X_t$ is reversible.

Comment: Divide by $\sigma$ to reduce to the $\sigma=1$ case.

Comment: @HoldenLee $\sigma$ is a matrix I think.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend one of the classic books

[1] **Stochastic Differential Equations. 
An Introduction with Applications**
By B. Øksendal

http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540047582

[2] **Stochastic Partial Differential Equations.
A Modeling, White Noise Functional Approach**
by Holden,   Øksendal, Ubøe and Zhang

http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4684-9215-6

[3] **Numerical Solution of Stochastic Differential Equations**
 by Kloeden, and Platen

http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540540625

Comment: Thank you for the reference. I have already looked in [1] and [3] but did not find the answer to my above question.

Answer (score 0):

(Let $\sigma \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be constant, $b : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ and $W$ a $n$-dimensional Brownian Motion.)

I believe this result comes from the following characterisation of a reversible process. For a diffusion equation

$$ dX_t= b(X_t)dt+\sqrt{2} \sigma dW_t $$

with an invariant measure $\mu$ with density $e^{-U(x)}$ (w.r.t Lebesgue measure), then

$$ X_t ~\text{is reversible}~ \Leftrightarrow  ~\text{the generator of the dynamics is self-adjoint in}~ L^2(\mu).$$

So we have to check $\langle \mathcal{L} \varphi, \phi \rangle_{L^2(\mu)}=\langle \varphi, \mathcal{L}\phi \rangle_{L^2(\mu)}$ where $\mathcal{L}$ is the generator for $X_t$. Note $\mathcal{L}$ is of the form
$$ \mathcal{L} = b\cdot \nabla + \Sigma ~:~ \text{Hess}, $$
where $\Sigma=\sigma \sigma^T$ and we used the notation $A~:~B= \sum_{i,j=1}^n A_{i,j}B_{i,j}$ for matrices $A,B \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. For the derivative operator $\partial_{x_i}$ it has adjoint $\partial^*_{x_{i}}= -\partial_{x_i} + \partial_{x_i}U$ so that

$$\nabla^* v = - \text{div}(v) + \nabla U\cdot v,~~\text{for a vector $v$}$$

and we can rewrite $\mathcal{L}$ as
$$ \mathcal{L}\varphi = -\nabla^* \Sigma \nabla \varphi + (b+\Sigma \nabla U )\cdot \nabla \varphi $$

One can then calculate using IBP (assuming the boundary terms are zero) and the product rule, that the adjoint in $L^2(\mu)$ is

$$\mathcal{L}^* \varphi = \Sigma ~:~ \text{Hess}\varphi - \Sigma \nabla U \cdot \nabla \varphi - (b+\Sigma \nabla U )\cdot \nabla \varphi + J \varphi  $$

where
$$ J= (b+\Sigma \nabla U) \cdot \nabla U - \text{div}(b+\Sigma \nabla U).$$

Rewriting things again noting what $\nabla^*$ is, we have

$$ \mathcal{L}^*\varphi = -\nabla^* \Sigma \nabla \varphi - (b+\Sigma \nabla U )\cdot \nabla \varphi + J \varphi.$$

Hence to be self-adjoint one needs that $$ b=-\Sigma \nabla U.$$